# Data type mismatch using Dlookup

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, type-mismatch

I'm building an order form with comboboxes. I would like to use the `Dlookup` function to display in a separate textbox a value based on the selection from a combobox. I have written the expression as an `AfterUpdate` event.

```
Private Sub cboSliding_SysID_AfterUpdate()

    SLPrice = DLookup("[Sup_multiplier]", "SliddingDoorstbl", "ItemSL='" & [Concat] & "'")

End Sub
```

`Concat` is a type Calculated field and it is a concatenation of three fields in table `SliddingDoorstbl` while `Sup_multiplier` is a type text. Unfortunately, I'm getting Run-Time Error 3464 Data Type mismatch in criteria expression. Need help please

Comment: I would expect to see the selected value from the combo box in your code somewhere? Are you trying to match this against the `ItemSL` column

Comment: Laurencce- The combobox value is Concat and I'm trying to mach it against ItemSL. As I mentionned, Concat type is Calculated whereas the value i'm trying to get is a Text type.